# setting an int pointer equal to a regular int

Tags: c, pointers, atoi

I am trying to set a pointer (processNum) equal to a regular int (processNumTemp).  How can I do this?  I tried just doing processNum = processNumTemp which gives an error since I am trying to set a pointer equal to a non pointer.  How can I make this work?  Below is my code:

```
int *processNum = (int *)malloc(sizeof(12));
  int processNumTemp;

  processNumTemp = atoi(argv[1]);

  processNum = processNumTemp;
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to copy `processNumTemp` into the space you allocated, or if you want to make `processNum` point at `processNumTemp`. If the latter then you should remove your `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

`processNum = &processNumTemp;`

This stores the address of `processNumTemp` into `processNum`. I believe this is what you're trying to do. You can then get the value by dereferencing the pointer. That is by using 
`*processNum`.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to your pointer just as `processNum`, you're referring to its address, not its content. If you want to change the contents of what the variable points to, you should use `*processNum`, otherwise you're changing *what* the pointer points to, not *the contents* of what it points to.

Let's say that `processNumTemp = 74`. In your code, you're telling `processNum` that it should now point to the memory address `74` which most likely is invalid. You're not telling it to *store* 74 at the memory address it's currently pointing to (which is probably what you want).

So either you can change the data that's being pointed to by doing:

```
*processNum = processNumTemp;
```

or you can change what the pointer is pointing *to*

```
procesNum = &processNumTemp;
```

The former copies the value that is stored at the address of `processNumTemp` and replaces it with what was previously stored at the location that `processNum` was pointing to.

The latter doesn't change the data that `processNum` points to, instead it changes *what* it points to. In this case, we're making it poing to the same thing as `processNumTemp` points to.

Answer (score 0):

`De-reference` your pointer to access the data stored there, then assign it to something of the same type.

```
*processNum = processNumTemp;
// * is the pointer de-referencing operator
// once you have exposed the data, now assign it
// to something of the same type.
```